# Paramiko ssh output not getting output as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, paramiko

Below is the code:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect("1.1.1.1",  username=username, password=password)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("set -units GB")
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("vol show -vserver vs1 -volume test_volume -fields size")
return stdout.read()
```

Output getting from code:

```
 vserver                          volume             size
 ------------------------  ------------------         ------
 vs1                       test_volume               1.07TB
```

Output from device:

```
 test01::> set -units GB

 test01::> vol show -vserver vs1 -volume test_volume -fields size

 vserver                          volume             size
 ------------------------  ------------------         ------
 vs1                       test_volume               1100GB
```

Looks like paramiko not executing commands in same channel. How do i get value "1100GB" in python script also?

Hint: Both command should execute in same session so that i will get expected output like in device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `client.exec_command()`, the commands are actually running in different exec sessions, so your call to `set -units GB` isn't actually active for your second call to `vol show -vserver vs1 -volume test_volume -fields size`

You could try separating the commands with a semi-colon and running them in one session

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(
    "set -units GB; vol show -vserver vs1 -volume test_volume -fields size")
```